# ASP.Net Using the Membership.CreateUser Method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-membership

I'm having issues using the membership.createuser method. My code is below, I get a null exception as runtime. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    Dim username As String = userNameTxt.Text
    Dim password As String = passwordTxt.Text
    Dim email As String = emailTxt.Text
    Dim status As New MembershipCreateStatus

    Dim blank As String = ""
    Dim provider As MembershipProvider
    Dim providerUserKey As New System.Object

    Dim user As MembershipUser
    user = provider.CreateUser(username, password, email, blank, blank, True, providerUserKey, status)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need concrete implementation of MembershipProvider abstract class
you can either create your own or use existing one. You also need to set it in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MySqlServer;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
...
  <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add 
        name="SqlProvider" 
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
        connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
        applicationName="MyApplication"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
        requiresUniqueEmail="true"
        passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx

then you can use Membership.CreateUser, no need to create instance, it's static
it has also a property for default membership provider set in web.config: Membership.Provider

Comment: this seems to have worked, im not getting an error anymore, but its also not adding the user to the membership table :(

Comment: well hard to say where is the problem what provider are you using?

Comment: I've set the default provider to "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" and then specified that provider with all the code above.

Comment: you have to use  Aspnet_regsql tool to create database for that provider. read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right about making your config setup concrete. I didn't include the defaultProvider, which caused it to stuff up. Working now!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim provider As MembershipProvider
```

then

```
provider.CreateUser(..
```

provider is null as you haven't actually created a new instance

you should be using
[System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.createuser.aspx)

Comment: I did try Dim provider As MembershipProvider = new MembershipProvider()
but i get an error saying "new cannot be used on a class that is declared 'MustInherit'"

Answer (score 0):

Use the shared methods on the Membership class. You will have to configure the membership provider to use in your web.config file.

Then it's simply:

```
Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email, blank, blank, True, providerUserKey, status)
```

For details on how to configure your membership provider, refer to [msdn Memberhip doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx)

Comment: how would i go about configuring the membership provider in the web.config file?

Comment: Edited my post with a link to the msdn doc. It depends on what type of membership provider you're using. There's an SQL and an Active Directory one available out of the box.